# Windows 10 Universal apps. What controls should I use for a hamburger menu?

Tags: c#, windows, win-universal-app

So I've got VS2015 RC and the Windows 10 tools. I was watching the //build day 2 keynote when I saw a really nice UI and [hamburger menu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamburger_button) which scaled really nicely.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/JxwoVZg.png]

Which controls would I use to implement the hamburger menu? There must be something better than my rectangle and canvas solution.

This part:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/wQLafCm.png]

Comment: What is a *hamburger menu*? What does it have to do with the image you posted (which is a rough sketch of a house floor plan in Fabrikam)? I have absolutely no idea what you're asking here.

Comment: I was terribly disappointed by the lack of burger options.

Comment: This part http://i.imgur.com/wQLafCm.png

Comment: @KenWhite See https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=hamburger+menu+icon

Comment: What a ridiculous name it is

Comment: @BrianRasmussen: Thanks. I shouldn't have to Google something to figure out what the poster is asking (and didn't in this case because it didn't make sense). I did enjoy the first link the search you linked turned up, though. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite lol, I didn't even see that :)

Comment: I think "sidebar menu" might be a better name, but I'm not a UI guy.  I'm just curious - does the name "hamburger menu" come from the idea that the icon that typically brings it up (three horizontal bars in a stack) kind of looks like a hamburger if you squint?

Comment: @MichaelBurr Yes, and Yes!

Comment: http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2015/04/implementing-hamburger-button-with.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an MSDN blog on creating a hamburger menu control:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/madenwal/archive/2015/03/25/how-to-create-a-hamburger-menu-control-for-windows-8-1-and-windows-phone.aspx

> This unfortunately is not an out-of-box control on Windows or Windows Phone and instead requires you to create your own custom built control for this UI paradigm.

Comment: Thanks. It's a shame there's no real solution

Comment: The control you want for Windows 10 is the [`SplitView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.splitview.aspx).

Comment: Look at https://github.com/faisalr/HamburgerBinding

Comment: How  to  integrate  this  control  into  new  solution..When Im  trying  to  integrate ,leftpane  is  not  coming..